# HTML 5 Issues on iPhone with Google IMA SDK - Skippable Event

Tags: iphone, double-click-advertising, google-ima

I am getting the following error:

> AdError 1005: The provided ad type: skippablevideo is not supported.

Is it a known limitation on iPhone devices? Because on iPad everything works properly.

Answer (score 3):

Ok it looks like this is a limitation on google's side please open the following url:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ima-sdk/jYE6j4_YCko/m6HuIkM9uKMJ

Where they say:

"We currently don't support skippable on iPhone because it's impossible for us to render a skip button on top of the video"